# chekin a folder with tf command in TFS?

Tags: tfs, command, checkin

I know that I can check in a file to the TFS but I wonder if there is a way to check in a folder using tf command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using tf add and checkin one can check in an empty folder.
However,
tf checkin /recursive will check in everything under a given directory.